# Incluir nombre del usuario en mail PHP

Tags: php, html5, email

Estoy haciendo un formulario PHP con el cual los usuarios pueden mandar correos a través de un sitio web. El código funciona perfecto, salvo por el hecho de que cuando recibo un mensaje, en el nombre del remitente dice "yo", como si me estuviese enviando un correo yo misma. Lo que quiero hacer, es que cuando me entre un correo, me figure como el remitente el nombre que el usuario puso en el formulario cuando lo completó.

Mi pregunta es: hay alguna manera de hacer que en el nombre del remitente figure el nombre del usuario que ingresó en el formulario?

Dejo el código de mi PHP:

```js
<?php
$nombre = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$tel = isset($_POST['tel']) ? $_POST['tel'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$casadx = isset($_POST['casadx']) ? $_POST['casadx'] : '';
$namecasadx = isset($_POST['namecasadx']) ? $_POST['namecasadx'] : '';
$hijos = isset($_POST['hijos']) ? $_POST['hijos'] : '';
$namehijos = isset($_POST['namehijos']) ? $_POST['namehijos'] : '';
$age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '';
$gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';

$to      = 'carla.paludetto@kickads.mobi';
$subject = 'Cotización Prevem';
$message = " La siguiente persona solicita una cotización:<br/>
<b>Nombre:</b> $nombre<br/>
<b>Teléfono:</b> $tel<br/>
<b>E-Mail:</b> $email<br/>
<b>Cónyuge:</b> $casadx<br/>
<b>Nombre del cónyuge:</b> $namecasadx<br/>
<b>Hijos:</b> $hijos<br/>
<b>Nombre:</b> $namehijos<br/>
<b>Edad:</b> $age<br/>
<b>Género:</b> $gender 
";

$headers = 'From: carla.paludetto@kickads.mobi' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Saludos, para ello dentro de "$subject = 'Cotización Prevem';" debes concatenar tambien el usuario ejemplo"$subject = 'Cotización Prevem'.$_SESSION['NOMBRE_USUARIO'];". esto suponiendo que el nombre de usuario almacenas en session...

Comment: Me da la impresión que usas el mismo emisor y el mismo remitente,cambia de otro remitente.

Comment: @Edgard estoy usando el mismo para probar. Pero como es para un cliente, me gustaría que como remitente figure `$nombre`, y en caso de que no se pueda, poner un nombre genérico como "Consultas"

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es como que el cliente que llena el formulario es el que te redacta el correo?

Comment: @Edgard Exacto! Que ese cliente figure como el que redacta el correo, como si fuera él quien lo envía!

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado! Para ello, puse la variable de `$mail`en la parte de `From`

```js
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit;
```